# Vimperator not working with Firefox 4 from official repository

Tags: 11.04, firefox

As the title says, with ubuntu 10.10 and firefox 4 from ppa it was working fine, any suggestions or is it a bug?

Answer (score 2):

See [this discussion](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.mozilla.firefox.vimperator/5973), so the max version in vimperator is set wrong. To fix this get the vimperator add-on from its [google code page here](http://code.google.com/p/vimperator-labs/).